# Saving text input from shiny permanently?

Tags: r, shiny, textinput, feedback

We are building a Shiny app and plan to share the link to shinyapps.io.

We are wondering if there is any way to collect feedback from users - e.g. is there a way to have a text input field and permanently save the inputs for us?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this project: [ShinyChat](https://github.com/trestletech/ShinyChat) which can be used as starting point for user feedback collection system.

Link to app: [Live Chat](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/chat-room.html)

So in theory you need to have global reactiveValues() where you store your log.Rds and then you add user input to that log file. You may want to use R package stringgr. Example code:

```
library(stringgr)
log <- reactiveValues() #This have to be outside shinyServer so that all users can see it

    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
        addFeedBack <- function(file, string) {
            ...
            return(modifiedFile)
        }
        observe({
            log$logfile <- addFeedBack(log$logfile, input$userFeedback)
        })
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I did some research and actually there is really nice article and example in an official shiny page: [Share data](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/share-data.html) So you will encounter some problems if you are planning to host your app on ShinyApps.io. and article gives solution for that.